# Cross-Compile SDL2 with DirectFB and add to a Buildroot root filesystem

Tags: linux, cross-compiling, sdl-2, buildroot, directfb

I am trying to create a root filesystem which includes SDL2 on DirectFB for an embedded linux 2.6.37 system (igepv2 board with TI DM3730 chip using OMAP).  I am using

- Crosstool NG
- Buildroot

Buildroot with DirectFB works fine - I can run the df_andi test. Unfortunately Buildroot-2015.08.1 supports only SDL1.2 so I am trying to cross-compile SDL2 from source and add it to the buildroot-created root filesystem.... as follows:

> LDFLAGS=-L/home/peter/igep2015/9Buildroot/buildroot-2015.08.1/output/staging/usr/lib
> CPPFLAGS=-I/home/peter/igep2015/9Buildroot/buildroot-2015.08.1/output/staging/usr/include
>
> DIRECTFBCONFIG=/home/peter/igep2015/9Buildroot/buildroot-2015.08.1/output/host/usr/arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabi/sysroot/usr/bin
>
> export CC=arm-linux-gcc
>
> ./configure  --prefix=/usr --host=arm-linux --without-x --disable-pulseaudio --disable-esd --disable-video-x11 --disable-x11-shared --disable-video-x11-xcursor --disable-video-x11-xinerama --disable-video-x11-xinput  --disable-video-x11-xrandr   --disable-video-x11-scrnsaver --disable-video-x11-xshape --disable-video-x11-vm  --disable-video-opengl --enable-video-opengles   --disable-haptic   --enable-fusionsound  --enable-video-dummy --enable-video-directfb  --disable-directfb-shared

which yields the following configuration summary with no usable video driver....

SDL2 Configure Summary:
Building Shared Libraries
Building Static Libraries Enabled modules : atomic audio video render events joystick power filesystem threads timers file loadso cpuinfo assembly
Assembly Math :
Audio drivers   : disk dummy oss
Video drivers   : dummy
Input drivers   : linuxev linuxkd
Using libudev   : YES
Using dbus : YES

The SDL2 config.log file shows SDL ./configure is not finding directfb
configure:20558: checking for directfb-config
configure:20592: result: no
configure:20604: checking for pkg-config
configure:20622: found /usr/bin/pkg-config
configure:20635: result: /usr/bin/pkg-config
configure:20678: checking for DirectFB 1.0.0 support
configure:20680: result: no

I checked my path DIRECTFBCONFIG and it contains directfb-config.   Any suggestions on what I am missing?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to build SDL2 outside of buildroot, it is much easier to just include the sdl2 package from current git:

```
curl 'http://git.buildroot.org/buildroot/patch/?id=a5c6ba4e' | patch -p1
```

Now you have sdl2 available in menuconfig.

Comment: Great - SDL2 is there.   But associated packages SDL2_gfx, SDL2_image, SDL2_TTF are still missing.   Are there other patches for them?

Comment: There are no packages yet for these other SDL2 libraries. But it should be fairly easy to make them based on the existing ones. If you do, please upstream them!